# How to use basic arithmetic operations in WHERE clause of CQL?

Tags: cql

I am trying to write a CQL query which looks like:

```
select * from mytable
WHERE timestamp >= unixTimestampOf(maxTimeuuid('2016-03-01 00:00:00')) /1000 
and timestamp <= unixTimestampOf(minTimeuuid('2016-03-31 23:59:59')) / 1000
```

and am getting this error:

> Invalid syntax at line 1, char XXX

If I change the query to

```
select * from mytable
WHERE timestamp >= unixTimestampOf(maxTimeuuid('2016-03-01 00:00:00'))
and timestamp <= unixTimestampOf(minTimeuuid('2016-03-31 23:59:59'))
```

it does not give any error but obviously I don't get the desired result since `unixTimestampOf` returns milliseconds whereas my `timestamp` column is storing seconds. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you store milliseconds in `timestamp` column too? Note that if your column type of the `timestamp` is `timestamp`, then you have milliseconds already.

Answer (score 0):

This JIRA ticket is what you're probably looking for: [Operator functionality in CQL](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7461). It's still unresolved, but it's moving on. One of its subtasks [Add support for arithmetic operators](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11935) has been marked as resolved recently, and is being merged in Cassandra 3.12, but it works for numeric data types only. I don't think it will work out of the box with your schema, you'll probably need to change timestamps to numeric data types.

HTH.